# Object property not working in Vue script but working in template

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm enjoying a fun project with vue. I have a firestore doc named "default" in "impostazioni" collection like that:

```
impostazioni/default = { 
  iniziata: false,
  finita: false,
  password: "abcd"
}
```

I want to retrieve the single properties and store them in the component. I do something like that

```
<template>
{{impostazioni}}
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "login",
    data(){
            impostazioni: null
        }
    },
    firestore: {
        impostazioni: db.collection('impostazioni').doc('default')
    }
 }
    </script>
```

If i do like that, in the template it prints what is expected to print:

```
{ "finita": false, "iniziata": false, "password": "abcd" }
```

But if in data i have:

```
data(){
  return {
    iniziata: null,
    finita: null,
    password: null,
  }
},
firestore : {
  iniziata: db.collection('impostazioni').doc('default')['iniziata'],
  finita: db.collection('impostazioni').doc('default')['finita'],
  password: db.collection('impostazioni').doc('default')['password']
}
}
```

and then in the template:

```
{{finita}} - {{iniziata}} - {{password}}
```

It doesn't work. It throws error like if `db.collection('impostazioni').doc('default')` was undefined.

If instead I store all the document into "impostazioni" and then in template I refer to `{{impostazioni.password}}`, I get the right element.

How can I get in separate variables the different elements of the document?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore is returning a promise that isn't resolve at the time you're trying to access the fields.

So either explicitly wait for the promise to resolve or use the more Vue-ish way of `computed` properties to reflect the different properties if you really need them in separate variables:

```
computed: {
  iniziata() {
    if(this.impostazioni)
      return this.impostazioni
    else
      return '' // default value here
  }
  ...
}
```